# Rationale for double colon in CSS

Tags: css

CSS3 introduced the double colon notation “in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements” [[CSS3 selectors spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements)]. For example, `:active` specifies a state and has therefore the single colon, but `::after` specifies a part of content and so has the double colon.

**The question is**: what is the exact technical reason to establish this discrimination? What problem does this discrimination solve?

Comment: Your question contains the answer. The double-colon notation was introduced solely to show a difference between `pseudo-elements` (`::`) and `pseudo-classes` (`:`). But for CSS 1 and 2 pseudo-elements, you can  safely use the single-colon for both.

Comment: You answered the question in the first sentence. Per their recommendation, note that it was last edited 4 years ago. Things have changed.

Comment: I've edited the question as it obviously wasn't clear what I was asking.

Comment: What could go wrong is you could get the two confused.

Comment: Pseudo classes are _states_, pseudo elements are, just that, _elements_. Adobe suggested some changes to the pseudo elements a few years ago and the [CSS Pseudo-Elements Module Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/) is currently a Working Draft. And the [CSS Selectors Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) introduced several new pseudo classes.  As more functionality is introduced to both the pseudo elements and classes it makes great sense to me separating the two.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious reason to have separate syntax is to prevent trouble when a pseudo element is introduced that has the same name as an existing pseudo class or vice versa, however unlikely.
This is just speculation. People in our field often have the reflex to overthink and overdesign and forget about YAGNI, or be terrified that a design choice they make will be second-guessed someday.